# Pass a slice of 1D array of 2D array through module in systemverilog

Tags: arrays, system-verilog

I have a module named `module2` which has 2D unpacked array for input and output. I want to pass each column of input and output to module `module1`. I tried to write the code in the following way. But it shows a syntax error in `.xin(xin[0:7][i])`.
What would be the correct syntax to pass a slice of array through module?

```
module module2 #(parameter n=20) (input signed [n-1:0] xin [0:7][0:7],
                            output signed [n-1:0] xout [0:7][0:7]);

genvar i;
generate
for (i=0;i<=7;i=i+1) begin:block1
module1 #(.n(n)) l1(.xin(xin[0:7][i]),.xout(xout[0:7][i]));
endgenerate
endmodule

module module1 #(parameter n=10) (input signed [n-1:0] xin [0:7],
                                  output signed [n-1:0] xout [0:7]);
...
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.xin(xin[0:7][i])` is not legal syntax for array indexing. You can do `.xin(xin[i][0:7])` or `.xin(xin[i])`.

You can expand the array to get all first index's `[0:7]` from a specific second index:

```
.xin({xin_rotate[0][i],xin_rotate[1][i],xin_rotate[2][i],xin_rotate[3][i],
      xin_rotate[4][i],xin_rotate[5][i],xin_rotate[6][i],xin_rotate[7][i]})
```

Or create another array for rotation:

```
always_comb begin
  foreach(xin[idx0,idx1]) begin
    xin_rotate[idx1][idx0] = xin[idx0][idx1];
  end
  foreach(xout[idx0,idx1]) begin // rotate back
    xout[idx0][idx1] = xout_rotate[idx1][idx0];
  end
end
for (i=0;i<=7;i=i+1) begin : block1
  module1 #(.n(n)) l1(.xin(xin_rotate[i]),.xout(xout_rotate[i]));
end : block1
```

Comment: This code works perfectly fine in VCS. But when I tried to run it in Design Vision environment it says  The construct `'foreach' is not supported` . Do I need to add genvar or something like this to make it synthesizable?

Comment: For some reason, some synthesizers have yet to add support for `foreach`. For now, you'll need to use a double for-loop. If you can, file a feature request to get it added in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

SystemVerilog only allows part selects (a slice) that reference a group of adjacent bits. You will have to add some combination logic to reform the array being passed through the ports.

```
for (genvar i=0;i<=7;i++) begin:block1
 logic signed [n-1:0] _xin[0:7], _xout[0:7];
 always_comb foreach(_xin[j]) __xin[j] = xin[j][i];
 always_comb foreach(_xout[j])  xout[j][i] = _xout[j];
 module1 #(.n(n)) l1(.xin(_xin),.xout(_xout));
end
```